# Trying to do simple_form_for on the following example code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to ruby-on-rails and trying to refactor the following form_tag into simple_form_for code and I was getting a weird error in log stating:

```
"customers_customers_customers_path' no methods found.
```

Any idea on which part of the code is wrong?

```
<%= form_tag  projects_path, :method => 'get', :id => "ajax_search_form" do %>
...
<% end %>
```

I refactor it into:

```
<%= simple_form_for @projects, :html => { :id => 'ajax_search_form' }, :method => 'get' do |f| %>

...
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please share your full log where this error raising? and route .rb also would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

simple_form_for is mainly used to associate the form to a model just like form_for does. In your code, you used form_tag to associate to a path, not a model. The right way to implement simple_form_for here is:

```
<%= simple_form_for :projects, :url => projects_path, :method => 'get', :id => "ajax_search_form" do $>
...
<% end %>
```